# How to sort logs files by date iso8601?

Tags: unix, sorting, logging, command-line

My logs are not ordered by date :

```
 1. 2013-09-13T09:44:10.581-0400 - 4mainthreadtest@test.com - (v1.6.88) - REPLAY >>  Scheduling replay in 2 seconds  
 2. 2013-09-13T09:44:10.546-0400 - 4mainthreadtest@test.com - (v1.6.88) - REPLAY >> Delay of 106803.116188 seconds  
 3. 2013-09-13T09:44:10.581-0400 - 4mainthreadtest@test.com - (v1.6.88) - REPLAY >> Hexoskin - replay completed  2013-09-13T09:44:10.535-0400 - 4mainthreadtest@test.com - (v1.6.88) - Hexoskin SDK - Playback ended with  0x0000
```

How can I order them ?

I looked at the command line sort but I was not able to sort by date iso8601.

Comment: you should be able to alphabetize them as long as they are all in the same timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sort by the second field (2013-09-13...), not the whole line.  You can specify that using the -k parameter:

```
sort -k 2 log.txt
```